# Input impedance butterworth filter with multiple feedback

Tags: filter, frequency, transfer-function, laplace-transform, input-impedance

I have a problem finding the input impedance of a Butterworth filter. The circuit is shown in the figure below:
[image]

I have calculated the transfer function between input and output; but now I have to find the symbolic expression of the input impedance seen from the \$V_{\text{in}}\$ generator.
I've tried a \$V_{\text{in}}/I_{\text{in}}\$ approach.
Since

$$I_{\text{in}} = \frac{(V_{\text{in}} - V_{\text{x}})}{R_1} $$

and $$ V_{\text{x}} = -V_{\text{o}}(sC_2R_2) $$

I find that
$$
Z_{\text{in}} =  \frac{R_1}{1+ W(s) sC_2R_2}
$$
Where \$W(s)\$ is the transfer function
$$
W(s) = \frac{V_{\text{o}}}{V_{\text{in}}}
$$
This sounds wrong to me, because the input impedance should decrease at high frequency, and in my case it's increasing.
Where am I wrong?
Thank for the precious help!

EDIT : I've checked it with SAPWIN, and it looks like the expression above is correct.
[image]
In the Picture there is the 1/Zin function.

Thanks to all for your help in solving the question!

Comment: You seem to have a capacitor in your path which tend to conduct better at higher frequencies

Comment: You're right. I've written the exact contrary of what I meant!

Comment: Vx is not −Vo(sC2R2)

Comment: As an alternative, you could inject a current of 1A and measure the input voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my visual analysis,

Zin(dc)=R1+R2//R3

for f>>f-3dB

@ f = infinity Zin = R1

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpkQ2X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

DC gain is -R3/R1  where Vx(f=0)=0

[**For visual aid on Vx see Attenuation, phase shift of xy for VI plot**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/#%24+0+5.4999999999999995E-5+10.20027730826997+65+5.0+50%0Ar+256+80+448+80+0+10000.0%0Ar+256+144+336+144+0+10000.0%0Ar+256+144+160+144+0+10000.0%0Ag+160+224+160+240+0%0Aw+448+80+448+128+0%0Ac+256+144+256+224+0+1.59E-7+-0.04269459360910877%0Ag+256+224+256+240+0%0Aw+256+144+256+80+0%0Aa+336+128+448+128+1+15.0+-15.0+1000000.0%0Aw+336+144+336+192+0%0Aw+448+128+464+128+0%0Aw+448+192+448+128+0%0Ac+448+192+336+192+0+1.59E-7+4.06804110490113%0AO+464+128+528+128+0%0Ap+160+144+160+224+0%0Ag+336+112+320+112+0%0A170+160+144+128+144+1+0.2+2272.7272727+5.0+0.8%0Ax+452+310+486+316+0+24+Vin%0Ax+453+339+502+345+0+24+Vout%0Ax+451+366+477+372+0+24+Vx%0Ax+455+398+557+404+0+24+R1++V+vs+I%0Ao+14+64+0+290+5.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0Ao+13+64+0+290+9.353610478917778+4.8828125E-55+0+-1%0Ao+5+64+0+290+2.3384026197294445+3.6537540933272573E-4+0+-1%0Ao+2+64+0+227+5.0+6.4+1+13%0A)
using Java with sweep. You can change any parameter

[image]

Comment: I totally agree. But what I want is a symbolic expression, in Laplace domain, of the input impedance. My approach is input voltage / input current. But I'm missing something.

Comment: KCL and KVL will find the correct result

Comment: Sure. But where?

Comment: KCL on all input nodes and use Vin+-Vin-=0 with zero differential impedance ( virtual "floating" gnd)

Comment: Ok, I've already used it in order to find the transfer function between in and out.
Now I need to find a relation between Vin and Iin.
The expression I've written above are correct?
The Vx expression comes out from the fact that Ic2= Ir2.
Now, using Vx in the Iin expression I find the Zin expression written above. That is incorrect. I don't know why.

Comment: also using KVL since Vin+=0 , Vin- must=0V

Comment: A symbolic analyzer will give you the answer - but, are you allowed to use this tool??

Comment: @LvW No, I can't. I need the analytic expression. Not a graph.
Thank you Tony,  but I'm not able to figure it out. Ok, even doing the KLC at Vx  I have: Ir1 = ir3 +Ir2 +Ic1.
Vin/ (ir3 +Ir2 +Ic1) = Zin? It gives me the same wrong expression I've already found.

Comment: this statement is wrong  \$ Vx = -Vo(sC_2R_2) \$  there is also feedback from R3 such that at s=0 Vx=0

Comment: In the original schematic Ic2 must be equal to Ir2. Vx comes out from there. I used it for the transfer function, it can't be wrong.

Comment: Fata Madrina - I spoke about a SYMBOLIC analyzer, which gives you the formula immediately.

Comment: Ah.  Wow! Can you  name me one?  I

Comment: SAPWIN is a symbolic analyzer which can calculate input and output impedances as well as the transfer function - all in symbolic form and (if you wish) as a function of frequency.

Comment: SAPWIN confirms the formula written above. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using superposition and yes, you have to factor in the transfer function because R3 (and the output) imposes a significant degree of complexity on the input impedance. First the easy stuff; you can forget C2, and R2 can be set in parallel with C1 because the op-amp has a virtual earth. So, it boils down to: -

[image]

Now you have two voltage sources and a few fixed value impedances so use superposition to calculate what the voltage at "X" is then you can calculate the current through R1 and then you have the input impedance.